# Excel conditional formatting based on a formula including a range containing the current cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to change the background of a cell as long as the running total in that column from start to that cell is less than a limit specified in a different cell.

Conceptually, the formula should look like this:

`=SUM(FIRST_CELL_IN_COLUMN:THIS_CELL)<LIMIT_CELL`

or, in more concrete terms:

`=SUM($C$6:THIS_CELL)<$F$10`

For example, suppose the value in cell `F10` is `19`, and column `C` looks like this (starting from C6):

```
10
5
3
2
1
```

Now, for illustrative purposes, let's compute the running total for each cell in the column (note that this column does **not** actually exist in the spreadsheet):

```
10
15
18
20
21
```

Remember, I want to change the background if the running total is less than the specified limit.  So, for this example, the first 3 cells should have their backgrounds changed.

My problem is that I don't know how to write the reference for THIS_CELL.  This is what I've tried so far:

`=SUM($C$6:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))<$F$10`

...but I get this error:

[image: error dialog]

Any suggestions on how I can make this work the way I want, or is that error message indicating that it's impossible?  I know I could cheat by adding a "running total" column and configure conditional formatting based on those results, but I want to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set your cell references carefully in the formula for formatting the sum column. Assuming that the sum values start in cell A1, highlight the sum column values and set the formula for conditional formatting as:

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)<$F$10
```

Comment: You're right; I was making it harder than it needed to be.  You got me pointed in the right direction, then I realized it was always off by one cell so I actually needed `=SUM($A$1:A1)-A1<$F$10`.  Thanks!